# layout.xml files not recognized until I invalidate cache and restart

Tags: android, android-studio

So I recently bought a new laptop, and I was too lazy to reinstall Android Studio all over again so I just copy-pasted it and it is working fine.. until I make a new Activity, I get this "*Cannot resolve activity.activity_name*" error. Once I hit File > Invalidate Caches/Restart it starts working fine again, but I have to go through this process EVERY time I make a new Activity.

Is there a way to end this misery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is to rebuild your project. If it still doesn't work you can go to your

"C:\Users.AndroidStudio{version}\". Here in both config and system folder and delete the caches folder. After this delete cache folder in .android folder present in "C:\Users\"
Then restart the AndroiddStudio.

Comment: Deleting the caches folder in system worked! thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

your problem can be thought and adjusted from these aspects, and you can also rule out whether the problem is caused by the following aspects.

- First, be aware that many settings are different between the old version and the new version.If you import the settings of the old version in the new version, it may cause strange problems in the use of the new version.I personally experienced it.
- Second, cache problems. As we all know, AS cache problems have always been pain points. Often because of cache problems, compilation failures, errors, and warnings for classes or methods appear. Therefore, it is recommended that you put the cache file in the .gradle directory in the user directory. If you delete, an excessively large cache will cause the memory loading speed to be too slow, causing the device CPU and memory to work inconsistently, resulting in a failure to refresh the AS in time and leading to real-time updates. The consequence of the deletion is that the next time you open the project, it will re-download Dependency package.
- Third, there is a problem with the memory size setting. If your new computer configuration is very high, it is recommended that you increase the memory size in the settings. For the specific setting method, please ask Google to get the results.